# Can symlink() be used to create links in another directory?

Tags: c, filesystems

Is there a way that I can use the function symlink() to create symbolic links to files and store them in a differnt directory in C?

For example /foo contains main.c and I want my program to create a link to it in /bar.

My question is can I do it directly in C or do I have to use a pipe and feed the file paths to a script that will create them?

Comment: Isn't it exactly what `symlink` does? Have you read it's `man` page?

Comment: You should be able to just use something like `symlink("/foo/main.c", "/bar/main.c");`.

Comment: @EugeneSh. oh whoops. I didn't think it was possible to a different path in the second parameter.

Comment: @SteveSummit the problem is something like: `symlink(elem->pathName, "/bar/elem->pathName");` I know that line is wrong but I dont know how to concatenate the new directory before the filename.